# how to write Test case for NSNotification for onWillEnterForgroundNotification

Tags: iphone, ipad, ocunit

How to write ocUnit test case notification when application enter foreground

```
-(void)onWillEnterForgroundNotification:(NSNotification)notification{

[self message:@"Hi" Value:@"G"];

}
```

@All

Any one advice me how to implement the test case for the above method.

Comment: Could you share what you use to register this method for the notification?